# Django REST same API for different countries

Tags: python, mysql, django, django-rest-framework

I have an ecommerce system that deals with multiple countries. The data in the database is separated based on the country codes.

But, I should have a single API that returns the products for each specific country.

I have domain names for each country: country1.abc and country2.xyz. 
When user enters to country specific webpage it should return only the products for that country. How can I differentiate the api (UI code also same)?

And, the DB also replicates for each country. Because, sometimes I need to scale for only one country.

Whats is the best approach to do it in Django.
How does a company like Amazon's system work for each country?

Comment: Maybe put country field into model for each product.

Comment: Yes thanks. there are pros and cons in both ways. Scaling and maintenance is easy if i go with seperate instance and on the other hand bug fix update is hard and cost .

Comment: I can put country id. then as jweyrich suggested all the recods will have the country id including orders transactions and so on maintenance becomes harder. How Amazon works? they have seperate instances running on for each country ?

Comment: Index your database and you will not have any problems with scaling.

Comment: If we shard the product table row by row for each country. Then We can't join the user tables and shard product table ? Can we do joins in sharding ?